# Is there possible to train own module using TensorFlow and then use it in OpenCV for detection?

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, training-data, dotnetnuke

I want to ask, can we train our own module (images) of some specific objects (maybe 2~3 objects), and then by using OpenCV DNN module detect those objects?

I have already tried a pre-trained simple with `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` in OpenCV, which works and is able to detect objects.

But now I want to train my own module with specific objects images, and as above using OpenCV detect those objects. I have searched a lot, but there is no a good tutorial to show how we can use TensorFlow train own module.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Of course you can train your own, and in fact if you look at the source for the sample you were using they provide a guide on how to train your own:

https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md

> In this section, we discuss some of the abstractions that we use for defining detection models. If you would like to define a new model architecture for detection and use it in the Tensorflow Detection API, then this section should also serve as a high level guide to the files that you will need to edit to get your new model working.